# solve for x - algebra and log function

Tags: logarithms

Have to solve this algebraic. I end up with the wrong result. I think I'm messing up with the log rules or something. Help please

$ 2 \cdot 1,3^x = 12 \cdot 0,9^x $

$ 1,3^x = 6  \cdot 0,9^x  $

$ x \cdot \log(1,3) = x  \cdot \log (6 \cdot 0,9  )$

Comment: That is not a correct application of the properties of the logarithm on the RHS. On that side, the exponent $x$ applies only to $0.9$.

Comment: So third line is: x * log(1.3) = x * log(0.9) * 6 ?

Comment: No. The third line should be $\log\left(1.3^x\right) = \log\left(6\cdot0.9^x\right)$. Then proceed by applying properties of the logarithm individually to each side of the equality.

Comment: But shouldn't I move the x outside the parenthesis and multiply with the log thing? Is it: x * log(1.3) = x * log(6) * log (0.9) ?

Comment: There is a property of the logarithm which is $\log(a^x) = x\log(a)$. However, on the RHS, your expression has the form $\log(b\cdot a^x)$, so you need to do something else first.

Comment: But isn't that what I've done? RHS: log(b*a^x) = x * log (a * b) = x * (6 * 0.9)

Comment: The property does not apply when there is something multiplying $a^x$ inside the logarithm.

Comment: Damn, didn't know that. So just RHS: log(6*0.9^x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ 2 \cdot 1,3^x = 12 \cdot 0,9^x $

$ 1,3^x = 6  \cdot 0,9^x  $

$ x \log 1,3 = \log 6+ x\log 0,9$

$x(\log 1,3-\log 0,9) =\log 6$

$$x=\frac{\log 6}{\log 1,3-\log 0,9}$$